# No space but `df`shows otherwise

Tags: linux, bash, shell, disk-usage

**UPDATE**

See answer. Found the problem.

---

I am downloading files that are quite large and place them under my `/zhome/5f/4/122845/Desktop/cleaned_files`. After some files, the system complains and won't allow me to download any further due to space. But looking at the below `df`, it seems like I have a lot left. I assume that I have to look under `zhome`or what? but here it says only 16% used. I am new to linux and I am using a hpc through ssh. Type is nfs.

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                        95G     0   95G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           95G  320K   95G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           95G  155M   94G   1% /run
tmpfs                           95G     0   95G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4                       72G  5.6G   63G   9% /
/dev/sda5                       34G   11G   21G  35% /usr
/dev/sda3                     1022M  4.0K 1022M   1% /rescue
/dev/sda2                      2.0G  210M  1.6G  12% /boot
/dev/sda7                      604G  108M  574G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                       64M  9.9M   55M  16% /boot/efi
beegfs_nodev                    98T   82T   16T  84% /work1
beegfs_nodev                   175T  112T   63T  65% /work2
beegfs_nodev                   142T  102T   40T  72% /work3
10.66.1.16:/ifs/hpchome/zhome  865T  132T  704T  16% /zhome
tmpfs                           19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/196326
10.66.0.102:/zdata/appl/linux   20T  1.6T   18T   8% /appl
10.66.0.102:/zdata/lsf10prod    18T   25G   18T   1% /lsf
tmpfs                           19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/234837
tmpfs                           19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/194863
tmpfs                           19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/230594
tmpfs                           19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/252995
tmpfs                           19G  4.0K   19G   1% /run/user/1002
10.66.0.102:/zdata/sw           18T  220G   18T   2% /dtu/sw
10.66.0.98:/zdata/scratch       47T   18T   29T  38% /dtu/hpc.scratch
tmpfs                           19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/260498
tmpfs                           19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/222845
```

Checking this:

```
-bash-4.2$ df -ih /zhome/
Filesystem                    Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
10.66.1.16:/ifs/hpchome/zhome   109G   17G   92G   16% /zhome
```

Checking `du` after a `cd` command:

```
-bash-4.2$ du -sh *
27G Desktop
32K Downloads
1.8M    Maildir
24K public_html
318M    sratoolkit.2.11.0-ubuntu64
127M    sratoolkit.tar.gz
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? Could be no space left on device, or quota exceeded or file too big.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a large amount of small files in the volume? You are possibly out of inodes.

You can check with `df -ih /zhome`

That appears to be a network mount -- this should work if it is NFS, but other types (cifs especially) may not, in which case you would want to run the `df -ih` command locally on the machine that has that volume.

Comment: So, I fetch large files (5G-10G) and clean them so they use only around 200M. However, this is done in parallel, so at some point the folder holds up to 5 files of full size (because I run in blocks of 5 in parallel). To answer your question, yes it contains small files, but only around 40 small files (200M) as of now.

Comment: moreoever, see my edit to the question. I still have 92G free in iNode

Comment: Ok, then it's definitely not inodes -- perhaps its a quota/root reservation issue?  What is the exact error message you receive when it fails to write anymore?

After doing a bit of looking around, it appears you may be saving to a share on an Isilon storage system -- in which case it is likely a quota issue and due to some complexities you aren't able to see the limits with `df` -- see https://www.dell.com/community/Isilon/Using-Linux-quota-command-pointing-to-an-ifs-nfs-mounted/td-p/6916630

Comment: I use a toolkit to fetch the data, and it's the toolkit that displays this error: `int: storage exhausted while creating directory within file system module - Cannot CreateFile: /zhome/5f/4/122845/Desktop/sra_sequences/sra/SRR827476.sra.lock`.

Regarding the quota. After reading on it, it kind of makes sense due to me being a student and there might be other students using the hpc. However, I am not able to check the quota allocation.

Comment: Can you describe the environment a bit? Who manages that remote volume you are connecting to? Is there a possibility you have a quota, and are hitting it?

Comment: It's my university that manages everything. And I think maybe the quota is the problem. I have written to them and await answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the problem is not due to INodes but because of quota as @James pointed out in the beginning. The `df` I posted in the question shows the space for all users of the HPC and not a single user as I thought initially.

Thanks to @James.